# How to change Kernel entry address through vmlinux.lds

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader

By default the Kernel boots from 0x100000 as it is defined in Kconfig file but have read somewhere we can also change the Kernel Entry address through vmlinux.lds file but not sure how??

Very first few lines from vmlinux.lds

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386", "elf32-i386", "elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
/* "ENTRY" is overridden by command line option "-e stext" in linux/Makefile */
 ENTRY(_start)
```

but now how do I map this _start to some address of my liking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to change the entry address?

Comment: We have a requirement of loading our image at a particular address ,when we try to load at default address its not working out for us.